# Does Access itself need to be installed so my .NET app can use an Access database?

Tags: .net, database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am developing a .NET program. If I use Access as a database for the purpose of running the program, should Access be installed on the host computer?

If is it not necessary that Access be installed, what should be used for proper running of the program (for example dll file)?

Also, it is important for me to have a low volume program.

Comment: Access is a terrible database engine. Use SQL Server Compact.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to have the full Microsoft Access *application* installed on the machine(s) on which you intend to run your .NET app. What you do need is to have the Microsoft Access Database Engine (a.k.a "ACE") installed on each machine. Note that the installed version of ACE (32-bit or 64-bit) must match the "bitness" of your .NET application (i.e., a 32-bit .NET application will need the 32-bit version of ACE, and a 64-bit .NET application will require the 64-bit version of ACE).

The installers for the Access Database Engine ("ACE") are available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255).